# Webform get submission details after or during submission

Tags: forms, hooks, webforms

How can I access the form data during or after submission?

Am using Webform REST for the submission of forms, but I don't seem to be able to retrieve the form data.

For now, I tried the following which gives me empty results:

```
function module_webform_submission_form_alter(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  \Drupal::logger("module.webform.data")->notice(json_encode($form_state, true));
}
```

I tried using HOOK form submit but it does not log anything at all. In fact, it looks like this hook is not triggered.

```
function module_webform_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  \Drupal::logger("module.webform.form_state")->notice(json_encode($form_state, true));
}
```

How can I access the form data during or after submission?

Comment: One thing you could do is to create a custom Plugin and use it as a submit handler. This way you'd have all the information you need. You may see example here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-a-webform-element#s-method-2-using-webform-handlers